# Can access external drive with elevated command prompt but not with explorer.exe

Tags: permissions, windows-explorer

I have taken owernship of all necessary folders on the drive. I can view, delete, copy, whatever I want to the files if I am browsing in an elevated cmd.exe, but no matter what, if I try to view those same files with explorer.exe I do not have permission.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could screenshot the actual error you are getting when you try to browse to the file share.   Is the drive USB?  Firewire?   eSATA?  Thunderbolt?

Comment: Your system administrator has configured the `Prevent access to drives from My Computer` group policy.

Comment: [Windows: “This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator.”](https://superuser.com/questions/1184157/windows-this-operation-has-been-cancelled-due-to-restrictions-in-effect-on-thi/1184222#1184222). I couldn't flag as a duplicate because you have not provided any specifics

Comment: There is no system administrator. This is a brand new installation of Windows as of yesterday. And it's the standard `You do not have permission` error, after it tries to load for ages

Comment: From an elevated Command Prompt, in the root of your external drive run the command `icacls .` and post the results in your question.